HTMX scroll position not restored on history back
When I click on a hx-boosted anchor tag and get pushed to the next page and press the back button, the scroll position I had in the original page is not restored, thus scrolls to the top.
Is there a way to configure this behavior or do I need to manually store previous page’s scroll position using Javascript?
